# Trying to change the id only works once and I have no idea why?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my page which contains both HTML and Javascript code. No matter how I set the initial value of the ID, it only works once. Which I find very strange!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />-->
      <title>Relay Trigger</title>

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js></script>
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div id="button">
        <button id="off">OFF</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#on").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("on").innerHTML="OFF";
        document.getElementById("on").id="off";
        alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
      });

    $("#off").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("off").innerHTML="ON";
        document.getElementById("off").id="on";
        alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
      });
    })
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you need to change you selector `ID` ?

Comment: Doing a Spark Core project and it looks better with only one button instead of two. Probably better ways but I'm a noob programmer :)

Comment: OK, than just give him a simple id `onoff` and you're done, no need to change it's ID :) also read the comments I left to the *accepted* answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$("#on").click(function(){/*...*/}`, there isn't any element with id `on`.
Then, that event handler isn't attached.

Moreover, when you use `$("#off").click(function(){/*...*/}`, you add the event handler to the element that, in that moment, has the id `off`. It doesn't matter if the id changes, the element is still the same and still has the same event handler.

To get the functionality you want, you can use event delegation to an ancestor with a filtering selector:

```
$("#button")
  .on('click', '#on', function(){
    document.getElementById("on").innerHTML="OFF";
    document.getElementById("on").id="off";
    alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
  })
  .on('click', '#off', function(){
    document.getElementById("off").innerHTML="ON";
    document.getElementById("off").id="on";
    alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
  });
```

Note this can be several times slower.

But a better alternative would be using `id="myButton" data-state="off"`, and

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    var state = $(this).data('state');
    $(this).data('state', state==='on' ? 'off' : 'on');
    state = state.toUpperCase();
    $(this).html(state);
    alert(state);
});
```

Comment: Delegation is not needed, also, delegating to `document`,`'html'` or `'body'` is an unnecessary overhead to the event delegation. He already has a static parent `#button`. But again, not needed at all since the **element** even if it changes ID is already there in the DOM.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sure. I wanted to show how to get that functionality in a general way, without considering his html. Fixed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class instead, ID's should not be used like this.

Comment: True, if you're gonna change the value, use classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `"` in your `script src`.
All you need is

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/pudif/3/edit)

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  $("#on, #off").click(function(){
    var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggler used as 1/0 boolean
    $(this).text(io?"ON":"OFF").prop('id', io?"on":"off");
  });

});
```

So inside this simple click function if you need to do more stuff depending on the stored `io` object value you can do:

**[PLAYGROUND](http://jsbin.com/pudif/5/edit)**

```
if(io){
   // do additional stuff if "on"
}else{
   // do additional stuff if "off"
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but since I need to add more events to the click action I'll @Oriol 's method. Learned a little again :)

Comment: @user3554980 than why not doing it like http://jsbin.com/pudif/5/edit ? :) you're welcome!

Comment: @user3554980 might be better, but I find it simpler! The var `io` can be also written like `var io= this.tog=!this.tog` which toggles and stores a boolean value right inside the element's Object `tog` property (or however you name it)!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happens is because when you registered the event handlers - the `#on` actually did nothing because there was no `#on` element in the document in that time

You have 2 options here:

1. set the handler only after you change the id:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#off").click(function(){
       document.getElementById("off").innerHTML="ON";
       document.getElementById("off").id="on";
       alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
   ```

   $("#on").click(function(){
           document.getElementById("on").innerHTML="OFF";
           document.getElementById("on").id="off";
           alert(document.getElementById("button").innerHTML)
         });
         });
       })
2. use "live" behavior:
   the `live` function of jQuery is deprecated - but you can do it by doing:

instead of

```
$("#on").click(function);
```

write

```
$(document).on("click","#on",function);
```